# Uncaught TypeError: this.$.AjaxPost.go is not a function - core-ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, polymer

I have written a HTML page for Password Reset for our website and we want it to be POST calls to the server. We are using polymer, and the code :

```
<dom-module id="user-password-reset">

<template>
    <div class="popup">

        <h5 class="popup-heading">Forgot Password</h5>

        <div class="popup-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="FormInput-UserEmail">Provide your Email Address</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="FormInput-UserEmail" placeholder="name@example.com" value="{{ email::input }}">
            </div>
            <br/>
            <div class="text-center">
                <button type="button" class="btn" on-click="onSubmit">Reset Password</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <core-ajax
        id="AjaxPost"
        auto="false"
        url="/api/user/email"
        method="POST"
        content-type="application/json"
        handle-as="json"
        on-core-response= _handleAjaxPostResponse
        on-core-error= _handleAjaxPostError
        ></core-ajax>

</template>


<script>
    Polymer({

        is: 'user-password-reset',

        behaviors: [
            Polymer.IronOverlayBehavior
        ],

        properties: {
            email: { type: String },
        },

        onSubmit: function( event ) {
            this.$.AjaxPost.params = JSON.stringify( { email: this.email } );
            console.log( this.$.AjaxPost );
            this.$.AjaxPost.go();
        },

        _handleAjaxPostResponse: function( event ) {
            /* Do Something */
        },

        _handleAjaxPostError: function( event ) {
            /* Do Something */      
        },
    });

</script>

</dom-module>
```

In the console :

```
<core-ajax id="AjaxPost" auto="false" url="http://localhost:8080/api/user/email" method="POST" content-type="application/json" handle-as="json" class="style-scope user-password-reset"></core-ajax>
```

and there is an error saying that :

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.$.AjaxPost.go is not a function
```

What should I do now?

Comment: Can you clarify the version of Polymer that you are using? Your `user-password-reset` element is being declared using the 1.0 syntax yet you are using `core-ajax` which is an old Polymer element from pre-1.0. The `core-*` elements are now no longer used and have been replaced with the `iron-*` elements. Have a look [here](https://elements.polymer-project.org/) for the current version of the Polymer elements. You will find one called `iron-ajax` which you should probably use instead.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I forgot to mention the version of polymer. We use Polymer 1.0, Thanks to Ben Thomas for pointing that out. And the solution turned out to be simple, no need to convert it to Json and use iron-ajax in place of core-ajax.

The code :

```
<iron-ajax
        id="AjaxPost"
        url="/api/user/email"
        method="POST"
        content-type="application/json"
        handle-as="json"
        on-response="_handleAjaxPostResponse"
        on-error="_handleAjaxPostError"
        ></iron-ajax>

var ajaxPost = this.$.AjaxPost;
            ajaxPost.params = { email: this.email };
            ajaxPost.generateRequest();
```

Note that, if you are using Post calls, then it is better to send the data in params, and not in body (read it somewhere). And while sending it, don't Json stringify it.

Answer (score -2):

I already had this problem sometimes back.

Try using `noConflict()`, because probably jquery is conflicting with WHAT you are running.

This page has helped me:
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Comment: This a comment, not an answer.

Comment: jQuery is NOT being used here.